# Can't remove read only attribute

Tags: windows-7, file-permissions, read-only

I have windows 7 and I've installed Oracle and my directory C:\app\jankiewj\product is read only. When I try to remove read only checkbox it ask me for admin permission. I've try to run explorer as administrator also try using attrib as this answer suggest [Windows 7 - Cannot remove read-only attribute](https://superuser.com/a/556409/50659) (running cmd as admin) but with no effect. I can't remove read only attribute.

Comment: What user account is the owner of the directory?  What user account is the owner of the parent directory?

Comment: @TOOGAM how can I check that?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are a local admin on the machine and that you already went through the  [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/326549) mentioned in the other answer that explains why the read-only box isfilled in the General Tab of the file properties.

However, if this is a directory ownership issue, you can do the following:

1. If you want to check the ownership of the parent directory and child directories, just run the following command in an elevated command prompt:

> icacls C:\ *folderpath*

2. To take ownership of the directory, use:

> takeown /F c:\ *folderpath*  /D y /R

R is a recurse switch that will help you take ownership of all sub directories as well

3. Assign full control by utilizing the following command. This will give you full control over the directory:

> cacls c:\ *folderpath* /E /T /C /G "UserName":F

Comment: Still nothing :(

Comment: Does it still ask you for admin credentials after you took ownership and assigned full control ?