# Unable to remove "read-only" attribute from XAMPP wp-content folder on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, xampp, wordpress

I've installed XAMPP on Windows 10, and installed Wordpress in XAMPP.

I am unable to upload images in Wordpress, receiving error:

> Unable to create directory
>   c:/xampp/htdocs/example/wp-content/uploads/2017/12. Is its parent
>   directory writable by the server?

I have removed the solid black read-only flag on `c:/xampp/htdocs/example/wp-content`, and applied to all subfolders, but as soon as I close the folder Properties window, the solid-black read-only flag is back.

From [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/20800/34252), I have downloaded Process Monitor, but can't see what is changing the attribute back.

I have tried the commands in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1010616/34252), setting the final command to set ownership for "Users", but the issue remains.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem become irrelevant when I went to Wordpress Dashboard > Settings > Media, changed `Store uploads in this folder` from

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\superiorit\wp-content\uploads
```

to

```
wp-content\uploads
```

This change allowed me to upload media.