# How to make folder and files in Windows 10 not read-only (writable)?

Tags: windows-10, security, file-permissions, visual-studio, read-only

Ever since the Windows 10 Anniversary update my folders have been marked read only. I want to make them un-readonly (if that is a word at all).

I've tried changing ownership of the folder, added Everyone to security users but it does not help.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: This has been a feature of Windows since XP. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/326549 . Duplicate http://superuser.com/questions/556397/windows-7-cannot-remove-read-only-attribute/556409#556409

Comment: @DavidMarshall I am having trouble writing to that folder building web apps using visual studio. When I try to build or clean I get error message saying file cannot be deleted access is denied. I did not want to confuse the post including details about visual studio therefore left it out. 

It is not just visual readonly attributes that is affecting me.

Comment: Command prompt admin : `icacls C:\* /grant Everyone:F /T /C`